# Найти happyNumber. Код не работает. Java

Tags: java, циклы

Отредактировал вопрос. Акткальная проблема,как же решить задачу с циклом?

```java
int num2 = (happyNum / 10000) % 10;
int num3 = (happyNum / 1000) % 10;
int num4 = (happyNum / 100) % 10;
int num5 = (happyNum / 10) % 10;
int num6 = happyNum % 10;
int sum1 = num1 + num2 + num3;
int sum2 = num4 + num5 + num6;

if (sum1 == sum2) {
System.out.println("да");
```

Comment: int happyNum = 123321;
        int num1 = happyNum/100000;
        int num2 = (happyNum/10000)%10;
        int num3 = (happyNum/1000)%10%10;
        int num4 = 
        (happyNum/100)%10%10%10;
        int num5 = 
        (happyNum/10)%10%10%10%10;
        int num6 = happyNum%10%10%10%10;

         int sum1 = 0;
         for(int i=num1;i<=num3;i++){
            sum1+=i;}


         int sum2 = 0;
         for(int i1=num4;i1<=num6;i1++){
            sum2+=i1;}

Comment: if(sum1 == sum2){
             System.out.println("Число 
         "+happyNum+" является 
           счастливым");
             System.out.println("Сумма 
          первых трех цифр = "+sum1+" а 
            сумма последних = "+sum2);

         }**

Comment: Представленный код _ничего_ не выдает.  Сумма _чего_ вычисляется в циклах, как вы думаете?  И зачем вам цикл(ы), если вы каждый разряд записываете в отдельную переменную?

Comment: И зачем для определения n-го разряда, вы несколько раз вычисляете остаток от деления на 10?  На результат это не будет влиять.

Comment: А что, если happynum изменять после каждого получения последней цифры так, чтобы на следующем этапе проще было?

Comment: @ПавелМиронов Как ты определяешь последнюю цифру любого числа? Или даже не так - та там делишь исходное число последовательно на 10, 100, 1000 и т.д. Вот тебе и цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант решения с отдельным методом для вычисления суммы цифр числа *в цикле*:

```java
static int sumDigits(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Затем этот метод вызывается для младших и старших разрядов 6-значного десятичного числа:

```java
int n = 123402;
int sumLo = sumDigits(n % 1000); // три младших разряда
int sumHi = sumDigits(n / 1000); // старшие разряды

if (sumLo == sumHi) {
    System.out.println("Happy!");
}
System.out.println("Младшие разряды: " + sumLo);
System.out.println("Старшие разряды: " + sumHi);
```

```
Happy!
Младшие разряды: 6
Старшие разряды: 6
```

Отдельный метод / функция для подсчёта суммы следует использовать, чтобы его было проще тестировать и в случае необходимости заменить другой реализацией.

Например, рекурсивное вычисление суммы цифр числа в десятичной системе счисления может выглядеть так:

```java
static int sumDigits(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n % 10 + sumDigits(n / 10);
}
```

Или если заведомо известно, что число десятичных разрядов не превысит трёх, то можно использовать и первоначальный вариант без цикла:

```java
static int sumDigits(int n) {
    return n % 10 + n / 10 % 10 + n / 100;
}
```

---

---

Вариант с циклами *без отдельного метода* по мотивам ответа Станислава Володарского с использованием переменной для определения разряда:

```java
int n = 123402;
int p = 1;  // степень десяти
int sum1 = 0;
for (; p < 1000; p *= 10) {     // первых три разряда
    sum1 += n / p % 10;
}
int sum2 = 0;
for (; p < 1000_000; p *= 10) { // следующих три разряда
    sum2 += n / p % 10;
}
if (sum1 == sum2) {
    System.out.println("Happy!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Цикл для рассчёта `sum2`:

```
int sum2 = 0;
for (int d = 100; d > 0; d /= 10) {
    int num = (happyNum / d) % 10;
    sum2 += num;
}
```

Так обычно не делают, но так можно решить вашу задачу.

Comment: Ее в начало циклов поставить,чтобы она заработала?

Comment: Сперва отложите требования про циклы и придумайте рабочий алгоритм.

Comment: Я могу придумать рабочий алгоритм решения данной задачи,без цикла. Но ментор требует наличие цикла обязательно,в задаче.

Comment: Это хорошо. Поместите рабочий вариант без циклов в вопрос. И спросите как его переделать с использованием циклов.

Comment: Цикл нужен для вычисления суммы цифр числа, и такое вычисление имеет смысл вынести в отдельный метод.

Comment: Вот решение без циклов. Как же его переделать с циклами,полскажите пожалуйста int happyNum = 123320;
        int num1 = happyNum / 100000;
        int num2 = (happyNum / 10000) % 10;
        int num3 = (happyNum / 1000) % 10;
        int num4 = (happyNum / 100) % 10;
        int num5 = (happyNum / 10) % 10;
        int num6 = happyNum % 10;
        int sum1 = num1 + num2 + num3;
        int sum2 = num4 + num5 + num6;

        if (sum1 == sum2) {
            System.out.println("да");

        }

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос - поместите туда ваш код.

Comment: Отредактирвал вопрос.

Comment: А можно поподробней,как это решение пристыковать к тому коду,который есть у меня,не понимаю.